# How can I make an Outbound call without being connected to it?

Tags: android, sdk, twilio, voice, outgoing-call

In my android application, using Java, I want to be able to click a button(the phone number will already be provided) and have Twilio send a call to that number, but I want a specific mp3 to play a message to the person it sent the call to. Currently it dials the phone number and connects the call with my application, which isn't what I want.

I downloaded the Programmable Voice Android SDK and the back-end server, and have it up and running. I tried to remove everything that I do not need but I am unsure of what within the code, makes the audio connect.

[edit]

I am using Android Studio Java for my android app. This is the code that is used to make the call. Copied from the Android Programmable Voice Quickstart but reduced unneeded code.

```
package com.twilio.voice.quickstart;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
import com.twilio.voice.Call;
import com.twilio.voice.CallException;
import com.twilio.voice.RegistrationException;
import com.twilio.voice.RegistrationListener;
import com.twilio.voice.Voice;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class VoiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "VoiceActivity";
    private static String identity = "alice";
    /*
     * You must provide the URL to the publicly accessible Twilio access token server route
     *
     * For example: https://myurl.io/accessToken
     *
     * If your token server is written in PHP, TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVER_URL needs .php extension at the end.
     *
     * For example : https://myurl.io/accessToken.php
     */
    private static final String TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVER_URL = "https://9ac7ae8f.ngrok.io/accessToken";

    private static final int MIC_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int SNACKBAR_DURATION = 4000;

    private String accessToken;

    private boolean isReceiverRegistered = false;
    private VoiceBroadcastReceiver voiceBroadcastReceiver;

    // Empty HashMap, never populated for the Quickstart
    HashMap<String, String> twiMLParams = new HashMap<>();

    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private SoundPoolManager soundPoolManager;
    private Button callbutton;
    private EditText phoneNumber;
    private Button endCallButton;
    private AudioManager amanager;
    private TextView userPhoneNumber;
    private String UserID;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;

    public static final String INCOMING_CALL_INVITE = "INCOMING_CALL_INVITE";
    public static final String INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID = "INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID";
    public static final String ACTION_INCOMING_CALL = "ACTION_INCOMING_CALL";
    public static final String ACTION_FCM_TOKEN = "ACTION_FCM_TOKEN";

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Call activeCall;
    private Call activeCall2;
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    RegistrationListener registrationListener = registrationListener();
    Call.Listener callListener = callListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice);

        // These flags ensure that the activity can be launched when the screen is locked.
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();

        if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            UserID = intentThatStartedThisActivity.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        }

        if (UserID == null) {
            Intent backToHomePage = new Intent(VoiceActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(backToHomePage);
            finish();
        }




        userPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        callbutton = findViewById(R.id.call_button);
        endCallButton = findViewById(R.id.end_call_button);
        phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.et_phone_number);
        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference(UserID);
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String uid = ds.getValue().toString();
                    if (UserID == uid) {
                        String number = dataSnapshot.child(UserID).getValue().toString();
                        userPhoneNumber.setText(number);
                        phoneNumber.setText("314");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        callbutton.setOnClickListener(callButtonClickListener());
        endCallButton.setOnClickListener(endCallButtonClickListener());

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        soundPoolManager = SoundPoolManager.getInstance(this);

        /*
         * Setup the broadcast receiver to be notified of FCM Token updates
         * or incoming call invite in this Activity.
         */
        voiceBroadcastReceiver = new VoiceBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver();
        retrieveAccessToken();

        amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        amanager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);

        /*
         * Ensure the microphone permission is enabled
         */
        if (!checkPermissionForMicrophone()) {
            requestPermissionForMicrophone();
        } else {
            retrieveAccessToken();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    private RegistrationListener registrationListener() {
        return new RegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistered(String accessToken, String fcmToken) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully registered FCM " + fcmToken);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(RegistrationException error, String accessToken, String fcmToken) {
                String message = String.format("Registration Error: %d, %s", error.getErrorCode(), error.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, message);
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, SNACKBAR_DURATION).show();
            }
        };
    }

    private View.OnClickListener callButtonClickListener() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Place a call
                twiMLParams.put("to", phoneNumber.getText().toString());
                activeCall = Voice.call(VoiceActivity.this, accessToken, twiMLParams, callListener);
                twiMLParams.put("to", "3143102934");
                activeCall2 = Voice.call(VoiceActivity.this, accessToken, twiMLParams, callListener);

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VoiceActivity.this, "Call Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        };
    }

    private View.OnClickListener endCallButtonClickListener() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // End a call
                if (activeCall != null) {
                    activeCall.disconnect();
                    activeCall = null;
                }
                if (activeCall2 != null) {
                    activeCall2.disconnect();
                    activeCall2 = null;
                }
            }
        };
    }


    private Call.Listener callListener() {
        return new Call.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectFailure(Call call, CallException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connect failure");
                String message = String.format("Call Error: %d, %s", error.getErrorCode(), error.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, message);
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, SNACKBAR_DURATION).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Call call) {
                //setAudioFocus(true);                Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
                activeCall = call;
                activeCall2 = call;
                amanager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(Call call, CallException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
                if (error != null) {
                    String message = String.format("Call Error: %d, %s", error.getErrorCode(), error.getMessage());
                    Log.e(TAG, message);
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, SNACKBAR_DURATION).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /*
     * Reset UI elements
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        soundPoolManager.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_INCOMING_CALL);
            intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_FCM_TOKEN);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                    voiceBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver() {
        if (isReceiverRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(voiceBroadcastReceiver);
            isReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    private class VoiceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(ACTION_INCOMING_CALL)) {
                /*
                 * Handle the incoming call invite
                 */
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Register your FCM token with Twilio to receive incoming call invites
     *
     * If a valid google-services.json has not been provided or the FirebaseInstanceId has not been
     * initialized the fcmToken will be null.
     *
     * In the case where the FirebaseInstanceId has not yet been initialized the
     * VoiceFirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh should result in a LocalBroadcast to this
     * activity which will attempt registerForCallInvites again.
     *
     */
    private void registerForCallInvites() {
        final String fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (fcmToken != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registering with FCM");
            Voice.register(this, accessToken, Voice.RegistrationChannel.FCM, fcmToken, registrationListener);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissionForMicrophone() {
        int resultMic = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        return resultMic == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissionForMicrophone() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                    "Microphone permissions needed. Please allow in your application settings.",
                    SNACKBAR_DURATION).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MIC_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        /*
         * Check if microphone permissions is granted
         */
        if (requestCode == MIC_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && permissions.length > 0) {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                        "Microphone permissions needed. Please allow in your application settings.",
                        SNACKBAR_DURATION).show();
            } else {
                retrieveAccessToken();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Get an access token from your Twilio access token server
     */
    private void retrieveAccessToken() {
        Ion.with(this).load(TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVER_URL + "?identity=" + identity).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String accessToken) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Access token: " + accessToken);
                    VoiceActivity.this.accessToken = accessToken;
                    registerForCallInvites();
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                            "Error retrieving access token. Unable to make calls",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the back-end node.js from the Android Quickstart back-end node.js github. I changed around the /makeCall to try and create a conference call that I was going to use to connect the caller and calle to my twilio number and have my twilio number play the mp3, but yet again failed.

```
require('dotenv').load();

const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VoiceGrant = AccessToken.VoiceGrant;
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
const defaultIdentity = 'alice';
const callerId = 'client:quick_start';
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;
const app = express();
// Use a valid Twilio number by adding to your account via https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified
const callerNumber = '3143552696';

/**
 * Creates an access token with VoiceGrant using your Twilio credentials.
 *
 * @param {Object} request - POST or GET request that provides the recipient of the call, a phone number or a client
 * @param {Object} response - The Response Object for the http request
 * @returns {string} - The Access Token string
 */
function tokenGenerator(request, response) {
  // Parse the identity from the http request
  var identity = null;
  if (request.method == 'POST') {
    identity = request.body.identity;
  } else {
    identity = request.query.identity;
  }

  if(!identity) {
    identity = defaultIdentity;
  }

  // Used when generating any kind of tokens
  const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
  const apiSecret = process.env.API_KEY_SECRET;

  // Used specifically for creating Voice tokens
  const pushCredSid = process.env.PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID;
  const outgoingApplicationSid = process.env.APP_SID;

  // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
  // containing the grant we just created
  const voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant({
      outgoingApplicationSid: outgoingApplicationSid,
      pushCredentialSid: pushCredSid
    });

  // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
  // containing the grant we just created
  const token = new AccessToken(accountSid, apiKey, apiSecret);
  token.addGrant(voiceGrant);
  token.identity = identity;
  console.log('Token:' + token.toJwt());
  return response.send(token.toJwt());
}

/**
 * Creates an endpoint that can be used in your TwiML App as the Voice Request Url.
 * <br><br>
 * In order to make an outgoing call using Twilio Voice SDK, you need to provide a
 * TwiML App SID in the Access Token. You can run your server, make it publicly
 * accessible and use `/makeCall` endpoint as the Voice Request Url in your TwiML App.
 * <br><br>
 *
 * @param {Object} request - POST or GET request that provides the recipient of the call, a phone number or a client
 * @param {Object} response - The Response Object for the http request
 * @returns {Object} - The Response Object with TwiMl, used to respond to an outgoing call
 */
function makeCall(request, response) {
// Use the Twilio Node.js SDK to build an XML response
const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
const MODERATOR = request.body.to;

// Start with a <Dial> verb
const dial = twiml.dial();
// If the caller is our MODERATOR, then start the conference when they
// join and end the conference when they leave
if (request.body.From == MODERATOR) {
  dial.conference('My conference', {
    startConferenceOnEnter: true,
    endConferenceOnExit: true,
  });
} else {
  // Otherwise have the caller join as a regular participant
  dial.conference('My conference', {
    startConferenceOnEnter: false,
  });
}

// Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
response.type('text/xml');
response.send(twiml.toString());
}

/**
 * Makes a call to the specified client using the Twilio REST API.
 *
 * @param {Object} request - POST or GET request that provides the recipient of the call, a phone number or a client
 * @param {Object} response - The Response Object for the http request
 * @returns {string} - The CallSid
 */
async function placeCall(request, response) {
  // The recipient of the call, a phone number or a client
  var to = null;
  if (request.method == 'POST') {
    to = request.body.to;
  } else {
    to = request.query.to;
  }
  console.log(to);
  // The fully qualified URL that should be consulted by Twilio when the call connects.
  var url = request.protocol + '://' + request.get('host') + '/incoming';
  console.log(url);
  const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
  const apiSecret = process.env.API_KEY_SECRET;
  const client = require('twilio')(apiKey, apiSecret, { accountSid: accountSid } );

  if (!to) {
    console.log("Calling default client:" + defaultIdentity);
    call = await client.api.calls.create({
      url: url,
      to: 'client:' + defaultIdentity,
      from: callerId,
    });
  } else if (isNumber(to)) {
    console.log("Calling number:" + to);
    call = await client.api.calls.create({
      url: url,
      to: to,
      from: callerNumber,
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Calling client:" + to);
    call =  await client.api.calls.create({
      url: url,
      to: 'client:' + to,
      from: callerId,
    });
  }
  console.log(call.sid)
  //call.then(console.log(call.sid));
  return response.send(call.sid);
}

/**
 * Creates an endpoint that plays back a greeting.
 */
function incoming() {
  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  voiceResponse.say("Congratulations! You have received your first inbound call! Good bye.");
  console.log('Response:' + voiceResponse.toString());
  return voiceResponse.toString();
}

function welcome() {
  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  voiceResponse.say("Welcome to Twilio");
  console.log('Response:' + voiceResponse.toString());
  return voiceResponse.toString();
}

function isNumber(to) {
  if(to.length == 1) {
    if(!isNaN(to)) {
      console.log("It is a 1 digit long number" + to);
      return true;
    }
  } else if(String(to).charAt(0) == '+') {
    number = to.substring(1);
    if(!isNaN(number)) {
      console.log("It is a number " + to);
      return true;
    };
  } else {
    if(!isNaN(to)) {
      console.log("It is a number " + to);
      return true;
    }
  }
  console.log("not a number");
  return false;
}

exports.tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
exports.makeCall = makeCall;
exports.placeCall = placeCall;
exports.incoming = incoming;
exports.welcome = welcome;
```

The matter that I get this done doesn't really matter as long as I am able to achieve the goal of getting the calle to answer the phone with the mp3 playing, where it doesn't play from the app initially.

Comment: This question is too broad, this is not exactly the place to ask how to build a mobile application. You should do some more research and ask a specific problem you might have, provide as much context as possible, including some code snippets etc.

Comment: @JoaquimLey Updated with my code and i'm more trying to learn how to manipulate twilio's services more than getting help making with creating my app.

Comment: Where is the mp3 file located? Is it on your phone or on your server?

Comment: @AlexBaban it’s going to be in google Firebase, but for now if I could just get twilio automated voice to work I’d be happy

Comment: I don't think you need the "the Programmable Voice Android SDK" for what you're trying to do, you just need to make a POST request to your endpoint from your Android app. I would get the back-end working first, making the requests with Postman from your desktop or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Alex said in the comments, you do not need the Programmable Voice SDK for the use case you are describing.

To trigger a call to someone, you want to [use the Twilio REST API to make the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). You will need to do this using server side code so that you don't inadvertently share your Twilio credentials. Once the call connects, Twilio will make a webhook request to your server again to find out what to do next. You should respond to this request with the [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to `<Play>` the mp3 file.

If you are comfortable carrying on with Node.js, then something like this should do the trick:

```
const twilio = require('twilio');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;
const callerId = process.env.MY_TWILIO_NUMBER;
const mp3url = process.env.MP3_URL;

const client = twilio(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/calls', (request, response) => {
  client.calls.create({
    to: request.body.To,
    from: callerId,
    url: 'https://example.com/calls/play-mp3'
  }).then(() => {
    response.sendStatus(200);
  }).catch((err) => {
    response.status(400).send(err.message);
  });
});

app.post('/calls/play-mp3', (request, response) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  twiml.play(mp3url);
  response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('The app is up and running');
});
```

All you'd need to do from here is replace the code that starts a call in your Android application with code that sends an HTTP POST request to the `/calls` endpoint in this little application and sends the number you want to call as the `To` parameter in the request body.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: considering i'm a novice developer and have not touched node.js except for with this server right here... I was unable to get it to work for me, but i'm going to keep trying and see if I can find some way around it to get it to work, thanks for the assist in the right direction

Comment: Are you getting errors that you can share? Would you prefer to work in another server side language?

Comment: Just the 404 Not Found error whenever I try to connect from my app to the /calls. I learned how to program through C# .Net, so I think I can give that a try. Would you mind if I emailed you about this?

Comment: Sure, drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com and I’ll get you sorted!